# Standard SQL throwing BAD INT errror

Tags: google-bigquery

How to avoid errors like "Bad int64 value: 72\017" in standard SQL in BQ?
Please let me know the methods to convert \017 to \17

Comment: I think we need more context here

Answer (score 1):

You may need to escape the backslash if that's in your data ... then perhaps have a peak at
REGEXP_REPLACE and SAFE_CAST ... this might be a good approach if your data is somewhat dirty.

```
#standard sql :

with cte as ( select 72 a , '\\01d7f' b union all select 82 , '\\018'  )
```

select  a ,   REGEXP_REPLACE(b,'[^0-9 ]','') , a / safe_cast(REGEXP_REPLACE(b,'[^0-9 ]','') as numeric)   from cte

```
a   f0_ f1_
72  017 4.235294118
82  018 4.555555556
```